# Dividing MainStoryboard in multiple Storyboards causing crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I recently wanted to divide my `MainStoryboard` into multiple organized Storyboard as I am using `Navigation Controller`. But now at run time my application crashes. I know that because I forgot to configure something with the division.

So I'm here to ask what it is. (*I also tried to localize it in the base folder of the project via the Xcode interface*).

Comment: You need to provide the details of the exception message

Answer (score -1):

My bad, I solved my problem, I forgot to specify the storyboard before instantiating my scenes in some of my files like that :

```
let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let menuVC : MenuViewController = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
```